# How can I do a FLIP animation in vanilla JavaScript with css flex-wrap: wrap;?

Tags: javascript, css, flip, typescript

How can I do a FLIP animation in vanilla JavaScript with css flexbox `flex-wrap: wrap;` as I have an expandable sidebar and the page content contains display: flex; items in rows and when the sidebar expands or collapses the first/ last items in each row suddenly change (jump to the next or previous row) as the container width changes?

I need this change to look like a flow animation from position A (beginning of a row) to position B (end of the previous row).

A similar animation is shown here:
https://codepen.io/techniq/pen/WxaxaR

But I need to do it in vanilla JS with CSS `display: flex;`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some code snippets, so we can better help you?

Comment: The project source code is really very long, I just need ideas for the technique not the code itself

Comment: I thought of doing it using the getBoundingClientRect() JavaScript function while adding an event listener for each window resizing and sidebar Hamburger sign click to record the top and left css properties before and after the event and then makes the animation by adding classnames